# Removing AM/PM from a timestamp since the user "should know that already"

Tags: time

I am not a native english speaker, so therefore I reach out to you with this question.

We have a case where a user "does something" in our application at a given time. The next day, the user will come back to the application and we will present this timestamp to our user.

We are discussing wether we should include the "AM/PM" indicator for this particular timestamp or not.

What would be the best approach here? Mostly reaching out to native English speakers.

Comment: Is the timestamp in 12-hour or 24-hour format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Retain the AM/PM for 12-hour format -- `08:35 AM` | `08:35 PM`.
Or choose the 24-hour format -- `08:35` | `20:35`.

One of the primary tenets of UX design is to [not make the user think](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/don-t-make-me-think-key-learning-points-for-ux-design-for-the-web). By skipping the `AM/PM`, you're forcing the user to see just `08:35` and think your system uses 24-hour formats when you're not, and probably interpret it as `AM` when it could be either `AM` or `PM`.

> ## #4 Clarity (Don’t Make Users Think)
>
> It is assumed as the most prioritized principle in UX Design.
> Designers are asked to make their design as clear as possible so that
> users could not get confused. If your users get confused, your design
> will receive a bad response from them.
>
> Source: [UXPlanet - 5 Principles of UX Design](https://uxplanet.org/5-principles-of-ux-design-d1579e7267db)

Comment: I know this is old, but note that modern Android and iOS devices have dropped the am/pm marker in 12 hour format.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to show just say You've visited at 15:33
avoid AM, PM, choose 24hr format.

Comment: I think that depends on your audience and your tone. In the US and English Canada, for instance, a 24-hour format is unfamiliar outside of a military context. In Britain and French Canada, 24-hour format is used in formal writing (newspapers, TV news bulletins), but conversationally people more often speak in 12-hour format.

Comment: How would a user know whether "11:15" is in 12- or 24-hour time?

Comment: 12-hour format runs from 1 am to 12 noon and then from 1 pm to 12 midnight. The 24-hour format uses the numbers 00:00 to 23:59 (midnight is 00:00).